# Golang program to check a string list of patterns in another string list - password cracking

Tags: performance, go, string-matching, password-hash

Community, I need suggestions on improving the following code:

To give the problem, the program does the following:

- It reads a file containing sha2 hashes into a string array.
- It accepts a starting number and computes the hash values consecutively.
- It checks for the computed hash with the hashes from the file (list) and prints the matches.

```
//FILENAME: passcracker.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "os"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
    "math/big"  
)

func isValueInList(value1 string, list []string) bool {
    for _, v := range list {
        if v == value1 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) <= 2 {
        fmt.Printf("USAGE : %s <PATTERNFILE> <STARTING_NUMBER>\n", os.Args[0])
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    fileName := os.Args[1]
    fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    
    strHashArr := strings.Split(string(fileBytes), "\r\n")

    startNum := new(big.Int)
    startNum.SetString(os.Args[2], 10)
    one := big.NewInt(1)

    //list := []string{ }
    var i int64
    for i = 0; i < 262144; i++ {
        h := sha256.New()
        h.Write([]byte(startNum.Bytes()))

        s := fmt.Sprintf("%x", h.Sum(nil))

        // Hash values are computed and added to a string list - A probable approach
        //list.append(s)

        if isValueInList(s, strHashArr) {
            fmt.Printf("Matched Hash %s for number %s\n",s,startNum)
        }
        startNum = startNum.Add(startNum,one)

    }
    // Probable approach to reduce the time
    // Computed hash string list is checked with the file hashes list
    // Function takes to string arrays 
    // Can it also use map or any other method for list in list comparison?
    //if isValueInList(list, strHashArr) {
        // get all the matched items and print the index value using the startNum value in a loop
    //}
}
```

The password hash file is at: https://pastebin.com/TWPxrb4R

To run the program, use

```
passcracker hashes.txt 1000
```

The program prints the matching hashes along with the identified number.

Since the program only computes a limited 262144 hashes, it will print faster.

Now to improve the program to output the matches faster, is it possible to compute the hashes into a string array and call a function to match the hashes from the file and return the matched indexes in a single call?

Since the problem is very similar to password cracking approach, but here the difference is to print the sequentially computed and matched hash value. It is something like a running user id which is consecutive.

Since the input hash file could get really big (in the tune of a couple of thousand hashes) and consecutive numbers could also be a large one, the program struggles even if the computation is just for 32K loop for a hash file containing a 10K hashes.

Currently for the sake of brevity, the number of hashes in the above file is 50 and loop checks for 256K numbers which executes faster.

Some help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: the best you have to do right now is to chse a better data structure to store and search for the hashes contained in the file.

Comment: yes. I'm trying a different approach and will post my findings as soon as there is some improvement in speeds. Also trying the answer provided by @steven-penny as well. Appreciate the comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to triple the speed:

```
package main

import (
   "bufio"
   "crypto/sha256"
   "encoding/binary"
   "encoding/hex"
   "math/bits"
   "os"
   "testing"
)

func BenchmarkFast(b *testing.B) {
   f, err := os.Open("hashes.txt")
   if err != nil {
      b.Fatal(err)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   s := bufio.NewScanner(f)
   hash := make(map[[32]byte]struct{})
   for s.Scan() {
      var dst [32]byte
      hex.Decode(dst[:], s.Bytes())
      hash[dst] = struct{}{}
   }
   var num uint64
   for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
      buf := make([]byte, 8)
      binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(buf, num)
      buf = buf[bits.LeadingZeros64(num)>>3:]
      sum := sha256.Sum256(buf)
      if _, ok := hash[sum]; ok {
      }
      num++
   }
}
```

Result:

```
BenchmarkFast-12         5983708               198.2 ns/op
BenchmarkSlow-12         1946358               614.7 ns/op
```

Comment: Much appreciated. This converts the hashes into hex and then checks for the matches. I think if the pattern contains strings, it will not convert to hex right? Also, any thoughts on the list to list comparison would be helpful. The program which I have posted is part of another program and there could be instances where the input file might contain obscure string hashes as well. Something similar like a JWT tokens where the character space might contain other characters apart from hex digits.

Comment: Another optimization you could use is to use a byte array instead of the counter and encoding each time.  Since it's sequential, you can bump the last byte and then bump prior bytes if it wrapped.

Comment: @StevenPenney I'm not sure what optimizations are out of scope for a question that is at least implicitly asking for help speeding up their code, but in some ways this is actually similar to the OP approach using `big.Int`.  The original code both does a manual carrying increment and a buffer encode; you got rid of the carrying increment, while I would suggest getting rid of the encode.

Comment: @KyleLemons Im not changing my answer. If you feel so inclined, post your own